# Windows NLB is not forwarding UDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, nlb, windows-nlb

I have setup Windows NLB which works fine with http. But it is not forwarding the UDP reply to the client.

Backgroud:

**NLB** - 192.168.1.10

**Host1** - 192.168.1.11

**Client** - 192.168.1.5

I am forward all the ports including UDP and TCP protocols.

[image: nlb port rules]

But through an application (from client) I send bytes to the 192.168.1.10(NLB) and it has reached to the Host1(192.168.1.11) I could see the logs.

But the reply message which has sent from the Host1 is not reaching the client.

On an other try I run the same application targeting to the Host1 directly without NLB.

The full duplex communication was fine. Client and Host1 could exchanging messages via UDP directly but Windows NLB could not do it so?

Answer (score 2):

When using NLB, the server doesn't send UDP packets from the NLB address. So if your client is expecting a packet back from 192.168.1.10, it won't work because the UDP packet will come from 192.168.1.11.